# Opencover not generating code coverage report in xml file

Tags: .net, sonarqube, code-coverage, opencover

The application is using dotnet framework 4.8.  I am running SonarQube scan and trying to generate code coverage report using OpenCover but the Gitlab job shows below error:

```
WARN: The Code Coverage report doesn't contain any coverage data for the included files. Troubleshooting guide: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/37151
```

I followed the troubleshooting guide and confirm that all the paths and parameters are correct in the SonarQube begin command.

I am using below command to generate code coverage:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:"UnitTestsNet48\IntAPI.UnitTests\bin\Debug\IntAPI.UnitTests.dll" -targetargs:"UnitTestsNet48\ExtAPI.UnitTests\bin\Debug\ExtAPI.UnitTests.dll" -targetargs:"UnitTestsNet48\WebAPI.UnitTests\bin\Debug\WebAPI.UnitTests.dll" -targetargs:"UnitTestsNet48\SomeAPI.UnitTests\bin\Debug\SomeAPI.UnitTests.dll" -output:"coverage.xml" -register:user
```